# Posicionar elementos en CSS

Tags: css

Estoy replicando la pagina de una marca de comida que no aclaro cual es por las dudas, y no entiendo como hacer algo y me está poniendo muy nervioso. Lo que yo quiero hacer es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo lo que llevo hecho es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando hace literalmente horas y no puedo, se va para abajo, o vuelve a subir pero tapa la imagen de arriba, no puedo mover la imagen de lugar, no se como hacer para que el h1, el p, y el input queden bien, me estoy volviendo loco. Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda, paso el código por si necesitan:

```
.contenedor-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 30%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.hijo-1 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 17px;
  border: transparent;
  background-color: rgb(248, 228, 201);
}

.negritazi {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

Nada, eso, si alguien me ayuda o tiene ganas de explicarme como se posiciona bien eso, le re contra agradezco.

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega el código completo de la sección que no te funciona, sería mejor que utilizaras un fragmento de código interactivo (Séptimo botón o Ctrl + M)

Comment: Buenas, podrías introducir también tu código HTML? para que podamos reproducir tu problema y encontrar fácilmente el error.

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más claro? ¿Qué es lo que no funciona como debería? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado?